# What is the most appropriate way for popular publications to report on statistics?

Tags: inference, reporting

I've been thinking about the [base rate fallacy][1], and other statistical reasoning fallacies that are easy to make. I also read a fair about of science and health news stories, and there are lots of instances of reporting of the stats that appear dodgy even to a non-specialist like me.

The question then, is how popular media could responsibly report statistical effects. The ideal would be to communicate complete results, while maintaining reasonably clarity for readers.

As a toy problem, I'd suggest a model statement about how to describe the link between smoking and lung cancer, which I imagine is an uncontroversial example. I assume that the necessary figures are available from several sources; the important thing, though, is how to report the effect rather than the specific figures.

Comment: An interesting first question! But note that those links are going to change over time, and possibly go dead (we have a serious problem with link-rot in our older questions unfortunately). To keep this self-contained and more relevant for future readers, do you think you could extract the key quotes? (And perhaps change the links to fixed ones at archive.org or similar?)

Comment: I made an edit to suggest people just find their own figures. (The point isn't the specific numbers, but how to report of them responsibly.)

Answer (score 2):

Recently, researchers have proposed a new methodology that takes into account model-selection uncertainty a bit better than the common methodology. It is called Post-Selection Inference, see PoSI.

It is a perfect tool to cope with statistical ignorance, but it has also its prices to pay. Most importantly, statistical tests need more "proof" to reject a hypothesis.

It would be a long post to explain it all. But check it out: Berk et al. (2013): http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aos/1369836961